# Android layout inflate exception in fragments

Tags: android, android-layout

my app is suffering from crash whenever i press back key. basically i have 4 fragments but app crashes only when it comes back on my first fragment.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: , PID: 5835
                                                                    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                                                                        at NewBookingFragment.onCreateView(NewBookingFragment.java:174)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:979)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1670)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:586)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:188)
                                                                        at HomeActivity.onBackPressed(HomeActivity.java:161)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2576)
                                                                        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:3171)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2831)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:534)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:50)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:241)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:50)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2429)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4580)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4535)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4070)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4123)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4089)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4199)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4097)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4256)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4070)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4123)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4089)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4097)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4070)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4123)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4089)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4232)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4419)
                                                                        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2480)
                                                                        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2074)
                                                                        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2065)
                                                                        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2457)
                                                                        at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
                                                                        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                                        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Code-

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);//line 161
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

XML Code which is causing issue:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.app.myapp.HomeActivity"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            class="com.app.myapp.TouchableSupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
             />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlDriverProgress"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/oval_progress"
            android:padding="5dp"
            >

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/getDriversProgress"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"

                />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlTimeRequired"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/oval_progress"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="10"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:id="@+id/tvNoOfMins"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="MIN"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:id="@+id/tvMinsHeading"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvNoOfMins"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llSearchBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_search_bar"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icSelectPickup"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="23dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_search"

                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/tvPickupAddress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:editable="false"
                android:elegantTextHeight="false"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:text="Select Pickup Address"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <!--android:textColor="@color/whiteTranparent" -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="faisal"
            android:id="@+id/dummyCenterTV"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pickupLocationPin"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/dummyCenterTV"
            android:src="@drawable/carpin" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutBookButtons"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnPickLater"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Book Later"
                android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:textSize="11dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rc_primary_button"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/label_pick_now"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:id="@+id/btnPickNow"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

i think map fragment section is the part crashing app. please have a look

Comment: And `NewBookingFragment.java` line 174 and the XML file that you are inflating there?

Comment: view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_booking, container, false);

Comment: Where's the `Caused by` part of the exception

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include `new_booking.xml`

Comment: on line 174 i have layout iflate code line
 
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_booking, container, false);

And when it goes to layout then crashed on Map Fragment Tag

Answer (score 0):

<s>Your error occurs here:
`com.app.minicabscouk.HomeActivity.onBackPressed(HomeActivity.java:161)`</s>

That's line 161 of your `HomeActivity`. You'll need to post the code from that class if you still can't figure it out yourself.

Hey, turns out I made a mistake! Disregard my above answer, sorry.

Check out the first line here:

`FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: , PID: 5835 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)`

That's your actual problem. Whichever fragment you're trying to create, there's a problem with the XML at line 16.

Comment: on line 16 i have map fragment